# Masked edit textbox default for time

Tags: asp.net, time, default, maskedtextbox

I have a masked edit textBox and want to use it for editing a timetable.
It works fine when editing but when I set a default (es. 20:00:00) it appears 200000 (no colon) even if I have set  Mask="99:99:99". 
The complete code for the textbox is:

20:00:00

Comment: are you using the Ajax MaskedEditExtender, or what textbox are you using?

Comment: Sorry I don't know the code I wrote didn't show up. I'm using a Ajax Toolkit Masked edit textBox extender. The cose is:      <asp:TextBox ID="tbDeadline_time" runat="server">20:00:00</asp:TextBox>
     <cc1:MaskedEditExtender ID="tbDeadline_time_MaskedEditExtender" runat="server" BehaviorID="tbDeadline_time_MaskedEditExtender"  AcceptAMPM ="false"  Mask="99:99:99" TargetControlID="tbDeadline_time" />

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you add  ClearMaskOnLostFocus="false" on the ajax Masked Edit control properties, it should keep the mask there for you.